# Parse comma separated key value pairs in stream java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a string which is comma-separated key-value pairs where keys are unique and it wont exist more than once and I want to split the string into key-value filtering based on just one key “s” and return the output for it as “GRADE3" in this example.

Below is the sample input string

```
String test = “s:03,g:05,st:06”;
```

i want to split the above String in Java 8 and read only value of key “s” which is “03” and that internally reads its values from HashMap below, so basically i want to return String “GRADE3" for 03 in this example.

```
private static final Map<String, String>  STUDENTS_MAP = new HashMap<>();

static {
    STUDENTS_MAP.put(“01”, “GRADE1");
    STUDENTS_MAP.put(“02”, “GRADE2");
    STUDENTS_MAP.put(“03”, “GRADE3");
}
```

could anyone help this in Java 8 using streams?

Comment: What have you tried so far, was there any specific part you got stuck on? We are happy to help with problems, but not to do your work for you. Hint: Use string splitting: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: I tried but I didn’t know how to write in Java 8, but yes thanks for the info, appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string and filter over its stream.

```
String test = "s:03,g:05,st:06";        
String search = "s";

String res = Arrays.stream(test.split(","))
                    .map(s -> s.split(":"))
                    .filter(x -> x[0].equals(search))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(x -> STUDENTS_MAP.get(x[1]))
                    .orElse(null);

System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using String split method:

```
String test = "s:03,g:05,st:06";
String key = test.split(":|,")[1];
String result = STUDENTS_MAP.get(key);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
GRADE3
```